# Issue to Append two list

Tags: c#-4.0, collections

I have 2 List

like

```
Class A{
   int rollno{get;set;}
   string Name {get;set;}
}

List<A> a=new List<A>();
List<A> b=new List<A>();
```

After lot of research i am notable to append List b to List a. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You mean you want to merge then into one? Also, how is B defined? Does it derive from A?

Comment: @antonijn Sir like if list a has 1,2,3 and list b has 3 4 5. then after merging i want a list which contain 1 2 3 4 5.

Comment: `B` is undefined. How should we tell you how to get an `A` from a `B` then?

Comment: Yeah, but does B derive from A? You can't merge two lists with different types easily if they are of different types, completely independent of each other. Also, you don't need to call me 'sir' ;)

Comment: Sir they are of same type. i have made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<A> finalList = new List<A>(a.Count + b.Count);
finalList.AddRange(a);
finalList.AddRange(b);
```

Also, if you are using LINQ, you could use the `Concat` method, as suggested by @TimSchmelter. I didn't post this method earlier, because the `AddRange` method is faster.

```
List<A> finalList = a.Concat(b).ToList();
```

Note that you might not even need the ToList. If you're not going to be changing (removing/adding) data after the concatenation, then you might as well store it in an `IEnumberable<A>`:

```
var finalCollection = a.Concat(b);
```